# bad character range :-' at position 6 exception in python

Tags: python, regex

I am comparing two strings but **excluding** the punctuation marks in both.

Here is my code snippet:

```
punctuation = r"[.?!,;:-']"
string1 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string1)
string2 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string2)
```

After running this code I get following exception

```
bad character range :-' at position 6
```

How to get rid of this exception? What's the meaning of "bad character range"?

Comment: Move the `-` to the last item inside the `[]` -- `r"[.?!,;:'-]"`

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/266162/4985099

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-` has special meaning inside `[]` in regular expression pattern - for example `[A-Z]` are ASCII uppercase letters (from `A` to `Z`), so if you need literal `-` you need to escape it i.e.

```
punctuation = r"[.?!,;:\-']"
```

I also want to point [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) which is useful for testing regular patterns.

Comment: @Mandy8055 for me this is matter of preference - solution with `-` as last insidec `[]` is minimally shorter (no need to use backslash), solution with `\-` show explicitly intent i.e. use literal `-`.

Comment: ```-``` is a special character, after escaping it as ```\-``` solved my problem. Thanks @Daweo

Answer (score 3):

A `-` inside a character class `[`...`]` is used to denote a range of characters, for example: `[0-9]` would be equivalent to `[0123456789]`.

Here, the `:-'` would mean any character between `:` and `'`.  However, if you look up the character numbers, you see that they are in the wrong order for that to be a valid range:

```
>>> ord(":")
58
>>> ord("'")
39
```

In the opposite order `'-:` (inside the `[]`) it would be a valid character range.

In any case, it is not what you want.  You want the `-` to be interpreted as a literal `-` character.

There are two ways to achieve this.  Either:

- escape the `-` by writing `\-`
- or put the `-` as the first or last character inside the `[]`, e.g. `r"[.?!,;:'-]"`